# ggplot2: Issues with changing binwidth of stacked histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having issues changing the binwidth of stacked histogram created with ggplot2.

It does not error out but seems to be ignoring the binwidth setting.

```
ggplot(trade.a, aes(x=variable1,y=value ,fill=category)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", binwidth=c(0,300),position ='fill') + 
    xlim(0, 300) + 
    xlab("Variable1") + 
    ylab("Count") + 
    ggtitle("Category") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + 
    theme_grey(base_size = 20)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using `stat="identity"` inside the `geom_bar` means that the data in `trade.a` has already been binned and counted (which is also implied by specifying a `y` aesthetic which points into the `trade.a` data). `binwidth` is an argument to `stat_bin` (the default stat for `geom_bar`) which does the aggregation for you. (Additionally it takes only a single value; the `breaks` argument can take a vector of breakpoints.) Thus to change the binning width for the `trade.a` data, you need to go back to the step where you did the binning. Or start with unbinned data and use the default `stat` for `geom_bar` with the `binwidth` specified.